# splitting XML string into multiple fileds and fetching field values

Tags: java, xml, string, split, stringtokenizer

Hi below is the XML string in one of my source field i need to fetch the field values and map to the target application.Please let me know how to achieve this functionality

```
pBigTxt = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Order OrderID="1234" CustomerID="123" UserID="AAA" DateCreated="15Dec2016" DealerOrderNumber="456" Total="678">
    <Line LineID="3" ItemID="6" Qty="6" DealerUnitCost="19" LineDiscount="0" LineAmount=""/>
</Order>
```

Thanks

Comment: post what you have done so far

Comment: Any inputs on this please?